Computational tools for spectral sequences
This is a generic question, but please bear with me. I am interested in learning about the tools, programming packages, and algorithms available online to work with spectral sequences. Specifically, I am interested in the following spectral sequences:

The Adams spectral sequence in stable homotopy theory.
The Atiyah-Hirzebruch spectral sequence in topological K-theory.
Spectral sequences used for studying vector bundles over algebraic varieties. Right now, I am not famililar exactly which spectral sequences do the trick here.

Ultimately, I am interested in studying the twisted equivariant K-theory of certain vector bundles. The base space will likely be an algebraic variety, but I have not yet narrowed the problem to this point. Right now, I am looking for computational tools that might be out there.

This exists, fwiw.
